# Fragment content gets cut off

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently developing an Android game. I have a problem with my content inside a Fragment. The content gets cut off and I am not able to find the problem. I only use the resource directory, where I define the different layouts. That is why I know the problem lies in the layouts. First I thought it has something to do with the fact I used `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. I found this solution on StackOverflow and I hoped that would also solve my problem. But this did not help me at all.

I have the `activity_game.xml`. There I have a placeholder for the current displayed `Fragment`. The content is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="y.trader.com.rhcloud.blackmonster.games.tradery.activity.GameActivity">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `Fragment` itself has the following layout defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/money"
    style="@style/traderY.TextCenter" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/location"
    style="@style/traderY.TextCenter" />

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/junkie_icon"/>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/drug_list"
    style="@style/traderY.List" />

  <TableRow
    style="@style/traderY.ButtonRow">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sell_drugs"
        style="@style/traderY.ButtonCenter"
        android:text="@string/sell"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nothing"
        style="@style/traderY.ButtonCenter"
        android:text="@string/nothing"/>

  </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the captured screen to show the problem.

[image: Screen capture]

As you can see, the last two buttons are being cut. I would like to avoid that and rather allow the user to scroll down. I am in a dead situation and I would appreciate any help. And I hope I manage to explain the problem good enough to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `ScrollView`, you can set `weight` for `ListView`. Try this solution:

```
 <ListView
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: I will give it a try, because the `ScrollView` did not do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. `ListView` instead of `TableRow`

Comment: OK, I used this and now the `ListView` has a scroll. And that way the content is fully displayed. I wanted to scroll the whole content, but this solution is also good enough. Thanks!

Comment: How/why does this work?  Why specifically add it to the ListView?  I'm having the same problem but just a bunch of Spinners and EditTexts in my fragment inside a Linear Layout

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your fragment layout in a [Scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to enable scrolling:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<!-- your layout here -->

</ScrollView>
```

You can see an example of it in use here: [Android ScrollView Example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-scrollview-example)

Comment: I will give it a try right away. Should I do this inside the `LinearLayout` of the Fragment layout or would you recommend to replace the `LinearLayout` with the `ScrollView`?

Comment: OK, I think I get your solution. I have to place the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`.

Comment: yes typically you would place `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`

Comment: I did not solve my problem. By using this I automatically shrink the `ListView` I have for displaying the list of all drugs you can sell. Now the list only shows the header columns and I have the scroll inside the list. I only see one row at a time.

Comment: Is the `ListView` itself scrollable at the moment?

Comment: It is, but like I said, it only displays one row at a time. It is hard to scroll and it even looks horrible.

Answer (score 0):

you should make your parent container height to match_parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="y.trader.com.rhcloud.blackmonster.games.tradery.activity.GameActivity">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That will not help me. I already tried that before I opened the question here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid wrapping your entire layout in a ScrollView, because it contains a ListView and nested scrolling views should be avoided. Instead, if you'd like the buttons to appear at the bottom of the list, you can make them the last list item in your ListView. You'd have to override [`getItemViewType(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) in your adapter to do this.

Another solution would be to place the buttons on top of the ListView, by putting the ListView and the TableView in a RelativeLayout, then declaring the TableView last.

Answer (score 0):

if your layout already contains a listview then applying parent layout as scrollview isnt a good practice. however if you still want to use it then you can set the height of the listview dynamically in order to make all its Items visible without scrolling. you can achieve this by using this small code

```
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(final ListView listView) {
            listView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
                    if (listAdapter == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
                    int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                        listItem.measure(
                                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));


                        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                        Log.d("listItemHeight " + listItem.getMeasuredHeight(), "********");
                    }

                    Log.d("totalHeight " + totalHeight, "********");

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = (int) ((totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1))));
                    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    listView.requestLayout();

                }
            });
        }
```

just pass your ListView Id to this method and it will set the listview height dynamically for you. and then you can use scrollview without any problem, and scroll the whole content as per your need.

usage:

```
    ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);

    YourListViewAdapter adapter = new YourListViewAdapter();

    yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set height here
    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(yourListView);
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)